Type of expansion process for a tank with orifice
Consider a tank filled with gas who is being discharged via an orifice. So, the gas flowing out of the tank is experiencing isenthalpic expansion and thereby a specific temperature drop, depending on the pressure drop to the outside. Equillibrium will be reached once the ambient pressure is established inside of the tank. Which process path did the remaining gas inside of the tank take? Assuming an adiabatic tank, is this an isentropic expansion?

Yes, it is an isentropic expansion.

Thanks! And sorry for having to ask again. Mods closed the other answer. It apparently is fine with fewer details, lol.
